# Place two UIImages in one UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uiimage

I was tasked to create a image viewer just like IKEA's catalogue viewer. It's completely out of my skills but after all I must try it.
I was once able to create photo viewer with UIScrollView like iPhone's Photo App, but IKEA's catalogue app is far more complicated as it has different parts per catalogue (title page, spread pages, back cover page). It cannot be done by my photo viewer code since it only requires simple array of UIImages. I have to separate them in several parts.

To achieve that, first I have to look for the way to put two UIImages into one UIScrollView, to make those two pages as one spread (two facing pages) zoomable UIScrollView. And our "web service" provides just an array of pages...
Is there any way to achieve this? I have searched around but all of them are the case about "marging" two UIImages, not putting them side by side as one UIImage. Should I have to create one UIImage from two UIImages then put it to the UIScrollView?

I know it's rather simple and noob question, but I really don't know where to start.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you need to keep the original images without manipulating them, then just place them next to each other on one screen?

Comment: Thank you for reply, Mark Struzinski! Well, that's what I would like to know how to do it. If placing just two UIImages, it would be simple. But this time I need to place them into "nested" UIScrollView...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make photo viewer then you must refere [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage). This will cache UIIamge with lazy loading. Use it's sample code. It will help you a lot.

All the best !!!

Comment: Thank you for quick reply, Yashesh! Although our photos are coming from the web, it will be used after downloaded (refered with locally) so SDWebImage won't be needed. Thanks for the tip though.

Comment: http://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=photo may be this will help you !!!

Comment: Thanks again for great list of the libraries! I made a photo viewer before (it was simple because they were just an array of images, not a "structured" images like in this case), but I'll definately check them!

Answer (score 0):

To nest UIImages in the UIScrollView, you should create 2 UIImageViews, figure out the frame dimensions you need, then call `[self.scrollView addSubview:myImageView];` for each UIImageView. For example:

```
UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image1"];
UIImage *image2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image2"];

UIImageView *imageView1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image1];
// put your specific frame values here
imageView1.frame = CGRectMake(100.0f,100.0f,200.0f,200.0f);

UIImageView *imageView2 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image2];
// put your specific frame values here
imageView2.frame = CGRectMake(300.0f,100.0f,200.0f,200.0f);

// This is a property tied to your scrollView, either created in code or in Interface Builder
[self.scrollView addSubview:imageView1];
[self.scrollView addSubview:imageView2];
```